# Bootstrap 3 video ontop of modal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button on my page that loads a submission inside of a modal.

Right above it, I have an embedded youtube video. In firefox, the Modal goes above the video just fine but when opening the modal in IE, the video is on top of it.

Is it possible to have the embedded iFrame behind everything?

```
<iframe width="100%" height="300" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/ScMzIvxBSi4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*This is not a good answer, but I do not see a better one getting posted. If a better one gets posted, then I will delete this one.*

In IE you generally have to remove the video because it is a COM object. COM objects are almost always top level.

Since I use iframes for my video container, I end up closing the iframe, and reopen once the modal form is closed.

Note that if you do this, there is still a chance that the video will continue playing after the frame is closed. I have ran into this with Youtube videos.

If you check out a few other sites like Bing video search, you may find some other ideas on how to overcome this.